# Split paragraphs into multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

I'm trying to put some HTML-informations in an array.

```
<p>Title 1</p>
<p><span>Content 1</span></p>
<p><span>Content 2</span></p>

<p>Title 2</p>
<p><span>Content 1</span></p>
<p><span>Content 2</span></p>
<p><span>Content 3</span></p>
```

I want to put these in an array with the fields "title" and "content". My problem is to put those p-tags together which has a span and belongs to the same title.

The result should be: (strip_tags for title and remove span for content)

```
[0]['title'] => 'Title 1',
[0]['content'] => ' <p>Content 1</p><p>Content 2</p>',
[1]['title'] => 'Title 2',
[1]['content'] => ' <p>Content 1</p><p>Content 2</p><p>Content 3</p>',
```

My attempt:

```
$paragraphs = explode('<p>', $html);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($paragraphs) ; $i++) {
    $paragraphs[$i] = '<p>' . $paragraphs[$i];
    if (strpos($paragraphs[$i], '<span') !== false) $content .= $paragraphs[$i];
    else $title = $paragraphs[$i];
}
```

But this will merge ALL content to one variable. I need the above array...

Comment: I would suggest you tale a look at [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for doing this. but try `$content[$counter] .= $paragraphs[$i]` for a start. You should increment `$counter` on title change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own counter for checking title change.

```
$output = array();
$last_title=''; // store last title for reference
$counter=-1; //your counter
$paragraphs = explode('<p>', $html);
for ($i = 1,$c=count($paragraphs) ; $i < $c ; $i++) { //start from the second as there is always a blank row
    $paragraphs[$i] = '<p>' . $paragraphs[$i];
    if (strpos($paragraphs[$i], '<span') !== false) {
        $output[$counter]['content'] .= trim(strip_tags($paragraphs[$i],'<p>'));
    }
    else $title = $paragraphs[$i];
    if ($title != $last_title){
        $last_title = $title;
        $counter++;
        $output[$counter]['title'] = strip_tags($title);
        $output[$counter]['content'] = '';
    }
}
print_r ($output);
```

Note: I still suggest PHP DOM.